# Homeomorphism from $S^1$ to square differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

It is commonly known that $f:S^1\to \{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\max \{|x_1|,|x_2|\}=1 \},\, f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{\max \{|x_1|,|x_2|\}}(x_1,x_2)$ is a homeomorphism from $S^1$ to the unit square. My question is if $f$ is even differentiable and if not if there is a differentiable injective map from $S^1$ to the unit square.

Comment: which paranmetrization of $S^2$ do you have in mind here?

Comment: @Thomas My bad, I meant $S^1$ of course.

Comment: You should look into the differentiability at those $(x_1,x_2)\in S_1$ which are mapped into the corners of the square (I would expect that it is not differentiable there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask whether $f$ is differentiable, I presume that you mean differentiable as a function $f : S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$: otherwise the question does not make sense, because the boundary of the square is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$, and hence has no natural smooth structure to which one can apply the question.

The answer to the presumptive question is no: if $f : S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ were differentiable then, letting $g(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $-1<x<1$, the composition $f \circ g(x)$ would be differentiable, but I'm sure you can show that composition is not differentiable at $x=\sqrt{2}$.

But there is indeed a differentiable injection $f : S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ whose image is the boundary of the unit square, in fact even a *smooth* injection. The tool you need is a differentiable bijection
$$g : [-1,1] \to [-1,1]
$$
whose one-sided derivative vanishes at each endpoint. It's not too hard to construct such a beast, and even worse beasts are constructed in analysis textbooks, for example a smooth bijection whose one-sided derivatives of all orders vanish at each endpoint.

You can then use this function $g$ to construct the desired $f$. For example, on the quarter circle of $S^1$ where $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \le x \le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $y \ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ you can define
$$f(x,y) = (g(\sqrt{2} \, x),1)
$$
Using similar formulas on the other four quarter circles, you can then check that the whole function is differentiable at the four points of $S^1$ where the quarter circles meet in pairs (and it is clearly differentiable at all other points of $S^1$).

Comment: I get the idea. You map each quarter circle onto the nearest edge of the square. But why would I use $(\sqrt{2}g(x),1)$? For this I would have to know that $\sqrt{2}g(x)\le 1$ when $|x|\le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. So basically I would need $|g(x)|\le |x|$. I'm sure that one can construct this but I'm not sure how. I thought I might use the function $h(x)=x\mathbb{1}_{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}$ and the mollifier $k(x)=\exp{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$ and then convoluting both where I have to choose the $\epsilon$ such that it works. But how do I do it such that $|g(x)|\le |x|$?

Comment: In order to make the functions "fit" at the borders, I think I have to construct $g$ such that $g(\sqrt{2}/2)=1$ and $g(-\sqrt{2}/2)=-1$ so shortening the domain to $[-\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2]$, don't I?

Comment: I made a bit of an error in my formula, it should not be $\sqrt{2} g(x)$ but instead $g(\sqrt{2} x)$. I'll correct that.

Comment: Alright, I think, I've got it figured out slightly different.
I defined $g$ by shifting and stretching the standard mollifier $\exp(-\frac{1}{1-x^2})$ such that it is bijective on $[-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}]$ to $[-1,1]$ and its derivative vanishes at $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Then I define $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(g(x),1)\quad\,\, |x|\le\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},y\ge\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
(-1,g(y))\quad x\le -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, |y|\le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\vdots
\end{cases}$. This should be fine, since I only use $g$ where it is defined. What do you think?